# Qt QRegexp Nullbyte

Tags: regex, qt

I am trying to extract a slice from a string using Regex. The issue is that the read file contains a nullbyte which messes up the regex I am trying to do. The binary data looks like this:

```
75736572 2c 7265766973696f6e 00 737472 2c 736f6d65
```

In String:

```
user,revision{HERE NULLBYTE}str,some
```

and I only want to extract the "revision" string. Regexes I have tried:

```
^[^,]*,([^\\d\\w_-]*),[^,]*$ = No match
^[^,]*,([^,]*)\x0000[^,]*,[^,]*$ = revision{HERE NULLBYTE}str
^[^,]*,([^,]*)\h000[^,]*,[^,]*$ = revision{HERE NULLBYTE}str
```

None of these work. Yes I need to do this with RegEx. The only thing I can do is make some post operations on the resulting string

The method looks like this:

```
QString Config::readInstanceValue(QString filepath, QRegExp regex, int group)
{
    QString instance_value = HGGW_NOT_SET_KEYWORD;
    QFile instance_file(filepath);
    if(instance_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        QTextStream in(&instance_file);
        while(!in.atEnd())
        {
            QString file_line = in.readLine();
            qDebug() << "READ CONFIG "<< file_line;
            if(regex.indexIn(file_line) != -1 && group <= regex.captureCount())
            {
                instance_value = regex.cap(group);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    instance_file.close();
    return instance_value;
}
```

Comment: If you can manage to read the string in with a null byte you may try `\\S+(?=\\x{0000})` with QRegularExpression.

Comment: you mean instead of the \x0000 part?

Comment: No, sorry, there is a comma, try `[^,\\s]+(?=\\x{0000})` as a whole regex. I guess `[^,\\s]+(?=\\x00)` will work the same.

Comment: Still no match with this

Comment: Please add the line of code showing what you library and method you are using

Comment: I added it and also some debug output of the read string. It is logged by qDebug as "user,revision\u0000str,some\u0000"

Comment: Try `([^,\\s]+)\\x0000` and then `if(regex.indexIn(file_line) != -1) { instance_value = regex.cap(1); }`

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. Why did my previous attempts not work?

Comment: You must have passed a wrong `group` argument. `^[^,]*,([^,]*)\\x0000[^,]*,[^,]*$` seems working, but you need to pass `1` as the *group* argument. What did you try? Did you pass the literal  backslash with it or not?

Comment: yep I called above function with the group 1 argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
QRegExp regex = "([^,\\s]+)\\x0000";
```

It matches and captures any 1+ chars other than a comma and whitespace into Group 1 and then requires a null char to appear (it is the left-hand context).

Then, you need to pass the `regex` to the `Config::readInstanceValue` method with the *`group`* argument set to `1`.

If you do not need to dynamically return specific group values, use

```
if(regex.indexIn(file_line) != -1)
{
    instance_value = regex.cap(1);
    break;
}
```